# is it possible: Using static library in iOS without including any header file?

Tags: ios, static, static-libraries, libraries

I made one really basic static library prints only one string on the screen. I made it for ios device and I added header files in copy headers --> Project. The `main .h` file is `SampleSubproject.h` .  After running I found the `libSampleSubproject.a` and copy to my project. When I am trying to use the library I call it in my .m file like

```
`#import "SampleSubproject/SampleSubproject.h"`.
```

it gives error

```
"SampleSubproject/SampleSubproject.h" is not found.
```

Is it possible to use headers from library without making them public?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, you want someone looking at the source not being able to see the available methods in the library? Can't they just look at the calls even if you could hide the header?

Answer (score 1):

As of i know, You can't. Since you are doing as a static library, you should add the header files.